# Easing functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This question sounds too trivial, but I could not find the answer anywhere.

I was browsing through the jQuery docs and saw some signatures like this.

```
.show( [duration,] [easing,] [callback] )
```

and

```
.animate( properties, [duration,] [easing,] [complete] )
```

At both places, easing is defined as

> **easing** A string indicating which easing function to use for the
>   transition.

But I don't see any documentation showing all the easing functions in jQuery.
From where will I get all the easing functions for jQuery?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard library only has `swing` and `linear`, however, [jquery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) brings in a ton more

Comment: It's very unfortunate that this isn't clearly said in the documentation next to "easing" in the description of the option.

Answer (score 5):

From the easing section of the animate doc:

> Easing The remaining parameter of
>   .animate() is a string naming an
>   easing function to use. An easing
>   function specifies the speed at which
>   the animation progresses at different
>   points within the animation. The only
>   easing implementations in the jQuery
>   library are the default, called swing,
>   and one that progresses at a constant
>   pace, called linear. More easing
>   functions are available with the use
>   of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery
>   UI suite.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/