# Smooth Scroll for anchor links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, anchor

I'm trying to get a smooth scroll effect for my anchor links on a clients website. For some reason the anchors stop working at all when I add the scroll code. I tried doing a pen with just a nav and the code and it worked fine, so it must be something else on my page causing the issue, help please??

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYegMK <-- its a bit barren but I had to delete the clients content for their privacy

```
(function($) { 

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {

      $('nav#cssmenu a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 95)
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
      });

    }); 

  });

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `linear` and `swing` easing.
You can find more info here [Easing functions in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611927/easing-functions-in-jquery)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you want your question to be upvoted or accepted, you should consider adding a little more explanation.